# How to get and use full installed text-to-speech languages list?

Tags: c#, .net, speech-synthesis

There is something really weird happening in Windows 10 speech synthesis.

First of all, even Windows displays different installed languages count in metro and classic control panels.

Metro app shows 5 installed languages, while classic control panel shows only 3.

I need to use **Microsoft Pavel** language, but my app simply don't see it!

```
SpeechSynthesizer ss = new SpeechSynthesizer();
var installed_voices = ss.GetInstalledVoices();

for (int i = 0; i < installed_voices.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(GetVoiceInfoDesc(installed_voices[i].VoiceInfo));

static string GetVoiceInfoDesc(VoiceInfo vi)
{
    return vi.AdditionalInfo["Name"] + " (ID = " + vi.AdditionalInfo["Language"] + ", " + vi.AdditionalInfo["Age"] + ", " + vi.AdditionalInfo["Gender"] + ", " + vi.Culture + ")";
}
```

The code above displays only 3 installed languages.

Also, when I use

```
ss.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Male, VoiceAge.Adult, 0, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ru-RU"));
```

I still get **Irina** voice that is female.

I tested **Pavel**'s voice and it's really installed and speaks something.

I use .net 4.0 C#.
Any ideas what's happening here?

[image]

Comment: did you try that with elevated permission?

Comment: @Simonare - Yes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that is some languages for some unknown reason can be used in metro apps only and can't be seen through `SAPI`.

We can fix this by changing registry.

This is fix example for Windows 10 x64 Pavel's voice that I took from somewhere in Internet:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\MSTTS_V110_ruRU_PavelM]
@="Microsoft Pavel Mobile - Russian (Russia)"
"419"="Microsoft Pavel Mobile - Russian (Russia)"
"CLSID"="{179F3D56-1B0B-42B2-A962-59B7EF59FE1B}"
"LangDataPath"=hex(2):25,00,77,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,69,00,72,00,25,00,5c,00,53,\
  00,70,00,65,00,65,00,63,00,68,00,5f,00,4f,00,6e,00,65,00,43,00,6f,00,72,00,\
  65,00,5c,00,45,00,6e,00,67,00,69,00,6e,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,54,00,54,00,53,\
  00,5c,00,72,00,75,00,2d,00,52,00,55,00,5c,00,4d,00,53,00,54,00,54,00,53,00,\
  4c,00,6f,00,63,00,72,00,75,00,52,00,55,00,2e,00,64,00,61,00,74,00,00,00
"VoicePath"=hex(2):25,00,77,00,69,00,6e,00,64,00,69,00,72,00,25,00,5c,00,53,00,\
  70,00,65,00,65,00,63,00,68,00,5f,00,4f,00,6e,00,65,00,43,00,6f,00,72,00,65,\
  00,5c,00,45,00,6e,00,67,00,69,00,6e,00,65,00,73,00,5c,00,54,00,54,00,53,00,\
  5c,00,72,00,75,00,2d,00,52,00,55,00,5c,00,4d,00,31,00,30,00,34,00,39,00,50,\
  00,61,00,76,00,65,00,6c,00,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\MSTTS_V110_ruRU_PavelM\Attributes]
"Age"="Adult"
"DataVersion"="11.0.2013.1022"
"Gender"="Male"
"Language"="419"
"Name"="Microsoft Pavel Mobile"
"SharedPronunciation"=""
"Vendor"="Microsoft"
"Version"="11.0"
```

Readme says "Thanks to Nonna Lavrukhina".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and tried multiple solutions but none of them worked. My requirement was not to have the specific voices found in windows 10 so i looked for other resources and found [this](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224).

I have tried installing some of them and my application recognizes them as being installed and they work as expected. Maybe you can find some voices there that suits your needs. Good luck!

Comment: Maybe you gave wrong link? This one is for `Microsoft Speech Platform - Runtime Languages (Version 11) `.

Comment: @Kosmos if you press download and scroll down you can see the actual languages available for download. For exemple MSSpeech_TTS_ru-RU_Elena.msi